# How can I control globally the automatically inserted linebreaks when using sprintf "%A" in F#

Tags: f#, formatting, printf

This code in an f# **program** (no fsi involved!)

```
let s = sprintf "%A" [1..100]
System.IO.File.WriteAllText ("c:/out.txt", s)
```

writes a file with content

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22;
 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31; 32; 33; 34; 35; 36; 37; 38; 39; 40; 41; 42;
 43; 44; 45; 46; 47; 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53; 54; 55; 56; 57; 58; 59; 60; 61; 62;
 63; 64; 65; 66; 67; 68; 69; 70; 71; 72; 73; 74; 75; 76; 77; 78; 79; 80; 81; 82;
 83; 84; 85; 86; 87; 88; 89; 90; 91; 92; 93; 94; 95; 96; 97; 98; 99; 100]
```

so there are **automatically inserted linebreaks**.

I need to get rid of these linebreaks. How can I control that?

(fsi.PrintWidth and similar settings do not apply here, fsi is not involved)

A remedy is to set the width to a very large value:

```
sprintf "%10000A"
```

But is it possible to define the default width globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%A` specifier is intended for plaintext, human-readable formatting: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting#a-formatting

Since that is the case, it will take this opinionated approach, and there's no way to configure it globally. Your workaround is one approach to not use the opinionated formatting. Another would be to write your own function to just append values to a string, and call that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
let s = sprintf "%0A" [1..100]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting#structured-values

Comment: from the doc: "Specifying a print width of 0 results in no print width being used. A single line of text will result, except where embedded strings in the output contain line breaks." thats a good one ;)